# Why can't I objects.get() a Django User by pk or id?

Tags: django

I'm trying to wire up an API endpoint to allow admins to disable a user via a simple, body-less PATCH command. However, for some reason my View's `get_queryset()` always returns a 404:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

# Disable a User
class DisableCompanyUserView(UpdateAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(str(self.kwargs)) # returns {'user_id': '12'}
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs[self.lookup_url_kwarg])
    ---snip---
```

I thought it might have been a type mismatch (i.e. self.kwargs['user_id'] was returning a string instead of an int) but I tried looking up the User by entering in `12` to the above return (as an integer, obviously) and still got back a 404. I also ripped out the shortcut function call, did the lookup manually, and *still* got back a 404:

```
try:
    return User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs[self.lookup_url_kwarg])
    # return User.objects.get(pk=12) # also returns a 404
except User.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404()
```

I'm looking at the raw `auth_user` table right now and there's a record in there with an `id` of `12`, so I know that that User exists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tgdn helped me realize that I was doing something really dumb: I was trying to filter down to a specific user in `get_queryset()` when I should have been returning all users.

I was able to get things working like this:

```
# Update a User
class DisableCompanyUserView(UpdateAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.all()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Which I simplified down to this:

```
# Update a User
class DisableCompanyUserView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_id'

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you try looking it up with

```
User.objects.get(id=theId)
```

Does that return any object?

`pk` is only a short form of `id__iexact`

**EDIT**

Have you tried manually doing

```
User.objects.filter(pk=yourID)[0]
```

This should get you results. Otherwise, try

```
User.objects.all()
```

And look if you can find the user you are looking for

Comment: I originally used `id` instead of `pk` (before reading that `pk` was better for instances in which a Model might defind a primary key that isn't named `id`) but the same thing happened.

Comment: Negative. I tried adding `queryset = User.objects.all()` to no effect, nor did replacing the `return` statement with `return User.objects.filter(pk=yourID)[0]` work

Comment: Wait so you are telling me that `User.objects.all()` does not return anything?

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually on the command line through `manage.py shell`?

Comment: I was being a bonehead, I should have been returning `User.objects.all()` in `get_queryset()` instead of trying to filter down to a single user.

Comment: Yes if `UpdateAPIView` extends one of the form mixins :) have a great day